# how can i return pchar type from delphi dll function?

Tags: delphi, dll, vb6, pchar

Vb6 code to run on the following error.

How can I fix the error?

How can I return a normal string?

vb6 code

```
Private Declare Function DllPchar Lib "C:\TEST\Project2.dll" (ByVal AStr As String) As String 

Private Sub Command10_Click() 
  Dim tmp as String 
  tmp  = DllPchar("123"); 
End Sub
```

Delphi7 code

```
function DllPchar( AStr: PChar) : PChar; stdcall;
```

Comment: What error? Please show it in full.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `PChar` is `PWideChar` in Delphi 2009 and later, but is `PAnsiChar` in earlier versions.  That affects interop operations, depending on which version of Delphi the DLL is written in.

Comment: Thank you. Been very helpful, thanks. 
Issue has been resolved. 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you haven't given much information about this problem. For instance, the error message. And the Delphi code for "DllPChar".

But never mind. The first thing I notice is that your Declare Function statement is returning a String. This will not work because VB is expecting a value of type BSTR to be returned. Delphi has a `WideString` type which is compatible with `BSTR`.

The reason why this is important is because VB strings are internally UTF-16, i.e. 2 byte per character Unicode Strings that are allocated by the COM memory manager. The Delphi PAnsiChar type is a pointer to an 8-bit ANSI character, and Delphi strings are allocated by Delphi's own memory manager. They are incompatible. However, there is a special case in VB6 where you can use `Declare Function` with a parameter `ByVal ... As String`, and VB handles and automatic conversion between a VB string and PAnsiChar *before* the call, and then between PAnsiChar and VB string *after* the call.

If you can't use BSTR in Delphi, your best bet is to rewrite DllPchar() so that it modifies the `AStr` parameter. Or alternatively, create a new parameter to return the value in.

If you can use BSTR, then you can modify `AStr` to pass it `ByRef` rather than `ByVal`. This will allow you to pass in a Unicode string from VB. You then return your result via the return value.

Comment: Thank you. Been very helpful, thanks. 
Issue has been resolved. 
Thanks again.